# WHERE is not working with AND after LEFT JOIN on time range, how can i correct this?

Tags: mysql

I want to select columns that are in the date range but within the join (left join specific), means all the bookings that have been booked but the departure date is not past today, whenever i put a WHERE AND function it's not working. where am i making a mistake?

I tried to remove the date in or the date our it works fine but it has no meaning at all

```
$currentTime = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM rooms
  LEFT 
  JOIN bookings 
    ON rooms.guest_id = bookings.guest_id 
 WHERE bookings.date_in <= $currentTime
   AND bookings.date_out >= $currentTime
 ORDER 
    BY rooms.id DESC
";
```

I expect rooms that are booked today and previous days but are still on use to be shown regardless of when they were booked, but those that their date out has passed should not be shown!am a newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use left joined  table columns in  where (this work as inner join ) you should move these condition in ON clause

```
    $currentTime = date('Y-m-d');
    $sql = "
    SELECT * FROM rooms 
    LEFT JOIN bookings ON rooms.guest_id = bookings.guest_id 
        AND  bookings.date_in <= '". $currentTime . "'
            AND bookings.date_out >= '" .$currentTime ."'
    ORDER BY rooms.id DESC";
```

or instead of obatin the actual datetime for php you can use  the mysql curdate() function

```
 $sql = "
    SELECT * FROM rooms 
    LEFT JOIN bookings ON rooms.guest_id = bookings.guest_id 
        AND curdate() between  bookings.date_in AND bookings.date_out 
    ORDER BY rooms.id DESC";
```

Comment: scaisEdge i did your method but it failed to fetch the results

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample, your actual result and the expected  result

Comment: scaisEdge i still don't know why the $currentTime var is not working with where function, am still searching why

Comment: answer  updated .. you need  a single quote  around var .. or use a mysql act date function

Answer (score 0):

After try different methods, this one seems to work though am not sure if its a best practice

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms 
LEFT JOIN bookings ON rooms.guest_id = bookings.guest_id 
WHERE DATE(date_in) <= CURDATE() 
AND DATE(date_out) >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY rooms.id DESC";
```